# Calling Invoke/BeginInvoke from a thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events, invoke

I have a C# 2.0 application with a form that uses a class that contains a thread.

In the thread function, rather than call the event handler directly, it is invoked. The effect is that the owning form does not need to call InvokeRequired/BeginInvoke to update its controls.

```
public class Foo
{
    private Control owner_;
    Thread thread_;

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> FooEvent;

    public Foo(Control owner)
    {
        owner_ = owner;
        thread_ = new Thread(FooThread);
        thread_.Start();
    }

    private void FooThread()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        for (;;)
        {
            // Invoke performed in the thread
            owner_.Invoke((EventHandler<EventArgs>)InternalFooEvent, 
                new object[] { this, new EventArgs() });
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }

    private void InternalFooEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<EventArgs> evt = FooEvent;
        if (evt != null)
            evt(sender, e);
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Foo foo_;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        foo_ = new Foo(this);
        foo_.FooEvent += OnFooEvent;
    }

    private void OnFooEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // does not need to call InvokeRequired/BeginInvoke() 
        label_.Text = "hello";
    }
}
```

This is obviously contrary to the method used by Microsoft APIs that use background threads like System.Timers.Timer and System.Io.Ports.SerialPort. Is there anything inherently wrong with this method? Is it dangerous in some way?

Thanks,
 PaulH

---

Edit: also, what if the form did not subscribe to the event right away? Would it clog the Form's message queue with events the form wasn't interested in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a threadsafe call, the method will be processed in the thread of the form.

Nothing wrong with it when looking at it from a conceptual perspective.

Timers are more elegant for such tasks, though. However, it could be that a timer with an interval of 10ms slows down the GUI, that's probably why Invoke was used.

You do not need a call to InvokeRequired, since it is clear that the Control is in an other thread. Also, BeginInvoke only needs to be called when you want to call a method asynchronously, which obviously isn't the case here.

Regarding your edit:
No, the message queue will not be clogged. No event will be fired if no handler has been registered. Take another look at your code ;)